# Как запустить последовательно файлы .sh из файла .sh

Tags: bash

Есть файл run.sh

В нём перечислены файлы:

```
# !/bin/bash

    test1.sh
    test2.sh
    test3.sh
```

Как запустить все эти файлы запустив один файл run.sh? У меня почему-то не получилось. Пишет  Can't open sh ,хотя когда запускаешь каждый файл отдельно из командной строки и ошибок не возникает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно указать, что файлы находятся в этой же папке

```
./test1.sh
./test2.sh
./test3.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

пишите вот так:

```
bash test1.sh
bash test2.sh
bash test3.sh
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]